# How do I get the word behind a # in a URL to display between html label tags

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a webpage dat greets you with welcome {name}. But the {name} has to be replaced with a name/word at the end of the url. The best I would find is after the # but something else is welcome.

I have tried to look up the different parts and put them together. But I don't know much about Javascript and it display the script that pulled the url instead of the output of that script.

Comment: The part beginning with `#` is `location.hash`. It includes the `#` character, you'll need to remove that in your code.

Comment: Instead of the hash, I would look into localStorage. It will allow you to store the name so you can use it on your website without the need for the hash

Comment: @imvain2 localStorage really has nothing to do with the URL and you would still have to pull the hash value out of the URL at some point (or send it from the sever to the page etc.)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss no it doesn't have to do with the URL. However, if they are getting the name I'm going to assume from user input, they could store it in localStorage instead of dealing with dynamically adding it to all of the URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var hash = location.hash.substr(1);` gets the value after the `#`

Feels like this might have been asked before.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I made of it: <script>
            var hash =location.hash.substr(1);
            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = hash;
 </script>

Comment: OR perhaps `.textContent = hashValue` but use was not part of the "how to get it" the question asked since there are several ways it COULD be put in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to extract the word and manipulate the DOM to update the label's content.

```
HTML:



 <label id="myLabel"></label>



JavaScript:

// Get the word behind the '#' in the URL


 const word = window.location.hash.substring(1);

// Update the label's content


 const label = document.getElementById('myLabel');
    label.textContent = word;
```

In this example, `window.location.hash` retrieves the portion of the URL after the # symbol. The substring(1) method is used to remove the # symbol from the string, leaving only the word behind it.

Then, the textContent property of the label element is updated with the extracted word, making it display between the label tags.

Make sure to place this JavaScript code after the label element in your HTML file.